# David Williams "Probability with Martingales" Page 114 Section 12.4 A symmetrization technique. Why is Uniqueness Lemma needed?

Tags: probability-theory

Question about section 12.4. "A symmetrization technique: expanding the sample space" on page 114 of Probability with Martingales by David Williams.

---

My question is why is the Uniqueness Lemma 1.6 needed in the following?

---

Suppose that $(X_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$ is a sequence of independent random variables on some space probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Make an exact copy $(\tilde{\Omega}, \tilde{\mathcal{F}}, \tilde{P})$ and $(\tilde{X}_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$. Define $$(\Omega^*, \mathcal{F}^*, P^*) := (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) \times (\tilde{\Omega}, \tilde{\mathcal{F}}, \tilde{P})$$
and, for $w^* = (w, \tilde{w}) \in \Omega^*$, define
$$X^*_n(w^*) := X_n(\omega), \quad \tilde{X}_n^*(w^*) := \tilde{X}_n(\omega).$$
The author states that "It is clear (**and may be proved by applying Uniqueness Lemma 1.6** [described below] in a familiar way) that the combined family $(X^*_n : n \in \mathbb{N}) \cup (\tilde{X}^*_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$ is a family of independent random variables on $(\Omega^*, \mathcal{F}^*, P^*)$, with both $X^*_n$ and $\tilde{X}^*_n$ having the same $P^*$-distribution as the $P$-distribution of $X_n$": $$P^* \circ (X_n^*)^{-1} = P \circ X_n^{-1} \quad \text{on} \quad (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}).$$

[Symmetrization Technique Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRrbV.png)

---

The Uniqueness Lemma 1.6 states that "if two probability measures agree on a $\pi$-system, then they agree on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by that $\pi$-system".

[Uniqueness Lemma Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyUNy.png)

---

My thoughts on how to show the claim:

For $A_1 , \dots , A_n, B_1, \dots , B_m \in \mathcal{B}$ we have
\begin{align*}
&P^* \left((X_1^*)^{-1}(A_1) \cap \dots \cap (X_n^*)^{-1}(A_n) \cap (\tilde{X}_1^*)^{-1}(B_1) \cap \dots \cap (\tilde{X}_m^*)^{-1}(B_m)\right ) \\
&= P^* \left((X_1)^{-1}(A_1) \times \tilde{\Omega} \cap \dots \cap (X_n)^{-1}(A_n)\times \tilde{\Omega} \cap \Omega \times (\tilde{X}_1)^{-1}(B_1) \cap \dots \cap \Omega \times (\tilde{X}_m)^{-1}(B_m)\right ) \\
&=P^* \left(\left ((X_1)^{-1}(A_1) \cap \dots \cap (X_n)^{-1}(A_n)\right ) \times\left ( (\tilde{X}_1)^{-1}(B_1) \cap \dots \cap (\tilde{X}_m)^{-1}(B_m)\right ) \right) \\
&=P\left((X_1)^{-1}(A_1) \cap \dots \cap (X_n)^{-1}(A_n)\right )\cdot \tilde{P}\left ( (\tilde{X}_1)^{-1}(B_1) \cap \dots \cap (\tilde{X}_m)^{-1}(B_m)\right )\\
&=P \circ X_1^{-1}(A_1)\dots P \circ X_n^{-1}(A_n)\cdot \tilde{P} \circ \tilde{X}_1^{-1}(B_1) \dots \tilde{P} \circ \tilde{X}_m^{-1}(B_m)
\end{align*}
where the last line follows from independence. In addition, for $B \in \mathcal{B}$ we have
$$P^* \circ (X^*_n)^{-1}(B) = P^*(X_n^{-1}(B) \times \tilde{\Omega}) = P \circ X_n^{-1}(B) \cdot \tilde{P}(\tilde{\Omega}) = P \circ X_n^{-1}(B).$$ Together these seem to prove both the claim of independence and of having the same law. I am wondering where the Uniqueness Lemma could be used?

Comment: You have proved the  independence criterion  for specific sets $A_1\times A_2\times...\times A_n$. To go from here to an arbitrary Borel set in $\mathbb R^{n}$  you need the Uniqueness Lemma.

Comment: Sorry would you mind explaining why I need to consider an arbitrary Borel set in $\mathbb{R}^n$? If I want to show that $\sigma(X_1^*), \sigma(X_2^*) , \dots , \sigma(\tilde{X}_1^*), \sigma(\tilde{X}_2^*), \dots $ are independent, don't I just have to show that for any $C_1 \in \sigma(X_1^*), \dots , C_n \in \sigma(X_n^*), D_1 \in \sigma(\tilde{X}_1^*), \dots , D_m \in \sigma(\tilde{X}_m^*)$ that $P^*(C_1 \cap \dots \cap C_n \cap D_1 \cap \dots \cap D_m) = P^*(C_1) \dots P^*(C_n) \cdot P^*(D_1) \dots P^*(D_m)$?

Answer (score 1):

$(X_1,X_2,..,X_n)$ and $(Y_1,Y_2,..,Y_m)$ are independent if

$$P((X_1,X_2,..,X_n)^{-1}(A)\cap (Y_1,Y_2,..,Y_m)^{-1}(B)$$ $$=P((X_1,X_2,..,X_n)^{-1}(A))P(Y_1,Y_2,..,Y_m)^{-1}(B))$$

for all Borel sets $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb R^{n}$ and $\mathbb R^{n}$ respectively. This is the definition. If you know this only when $A$ and $B$ are measurable rectangles, then you will have to use the uniqueness lemma to finish the proof.

[Measurable rectangles form a $\pi-$ system].

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, it seems that $(X_1^* , \dots , X_n^*)$ and $(\tilde{X}_1^* , \dots \tilde{X}_m^*)$  are independent since for any Borel $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and Borel $B \in \mathbb{R}^m$ we have $$P^*\left ((X_1^* , \dots , X_n^*)^{-1}(A) \cap (\tilde{X}_1^* , \dots \tilde{X}_m^*)^{-1}(B)\right ) = P^*((X_1 , \dots , X_n)^{-1}(A) \times (\tilde{X}_1 , \dots , \tilde{X}_m)^{-1}(B)) = P((X_1 , \dots , X_n)^{-1}(A)) \cdot \tilde{P}(\tilde{X}_1 , \dots , \tilde{X}_m)^{-1}(B)).$$ So, I'm still not sure that the Uniqueness Lemma is necessary to show this.

Comment: It also seems that the author only states that $(X^*_n : n \in \mathbb{N}) \cup (\tilde{X}^*_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$ is a family of independent random variables, which would only require showing that $\sigma(X^*_1), \sigma(X_2^*), \dots, \sigma(\tilde{X}^*_1), \sigma(\tilde{X}_2^*), \dots $ are independent. Not that $\sigma(X^*_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$ and $\sigma(\tilde{X}^*_n : n \in \mathbb{N})$ are independent. Although, I agree that the Uniqueness Lemma could be used to show that these two statements are equivalent (in general).